# Is Facebook Mention Tagging Autocomplete Possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tagging

I am trying to implement a feature in my app using Facebook's Mention Tagging API. Most articles online reference the blog post [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/21/bringing-mention-tagging-to-open-graph/), which then links to a [broken documentation link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/). I am wondering if this is even possible, as I cannot find any resources on this.

1. In my app, let's say I have the proper OAuth tokens for the user with all permissions enabled. Let's also I also went through Facebook's approval flow for my app and it has been approved to use this.
2. The user has 3 Facebook friends, **John Smith**, **Johnathan White**, and **Joe Roberts**.
3. Within my app, the user types "@Jo" and an autocomplete dropdown list will appear:

> John Smith
>
> Johnathan White
>
> Joe Roberts

When the user types "@Joh", this dropdown list will appear:

> John Smith
>
> Johnathan White

4. The user will select **John Smith** from my app's dropdown menu and publish the post to Facebook. From Facebook, **John Smith** will be mentioned and the text will link to **John Smith**'s Facebook page.

Now I already know how to retrieve **ALL** of my friends via taggable_friends API (step 2). I also know how to publish to facebook (step 4). The issue is step 3, as I cannot find any resources on how to implement this.

Is there a Graph API endpoint or an Open Graph concept that allows me to mimic Facebook's autocomplete tagging feature? Looking for something where I am making a separate HTTP request for each letter being typed. I also cannot store a user's friends list into my application's persistent storage.

Is this even possible or is this concept deprecated? Would really appreciate just some pointers to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No there is no such API. You will have to do it on your side

Comment: Be aware that this does not work for normal posts, this is for Open Graph stories only.